# How to remove duplicate uris from marklogic database?

Tags: marklogic

I am getting the following error in the marklogic database :-

```
 Error in rebalance of forest legacy-1: XDMP-DBDUPURI: URI 119560892619185780771.xml found in forests legacy-1 and legacy-2 with ts=0
```

The error is giving only the fragment id and i want to delete the document which is duplicate in two forests. How to find the document uri from the fragment 119560892619185780771.xml ?

Comment: the fragment ID is a number. If it ends with ".xml" then it's likely the actual URI of the doc, not an ID.

Comment: but when i search it in the Database it returns zero results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Knowledgebase article explains quite a bit about duplicate URIS including how they might be created, how to find them and how to address the issue.

[Understanding XDMP-DBDUPURI exceptions, how they can occur and how to prevent them](https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/understanding-xdmp-dbdupuri-exceptions-how-they-can-occur-and-how-to-prevent-them)